# In-app review black background behind bottom sheet

Tags: android, google-play-services, bottom-sheet, review

In-app review bottom sheet has a strange black background under it instead of regular dim. The dialog is shown using the sample code from the documentation as below:

```
context?.let { ctx ->
            val manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(ctx)
            val request = manager.requestReviewFlow()
            request.addOnSuccessListener { reviewInfo ->
                activity?.let {
                    val flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(requireActivity(), reviewInfo)
                    flow.addOnSuccessListener {
                    //Empty
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is an example screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out everything is normal at my end. It just happens that Samsung One UI shows this bottom sheet in such a strange way while it is fine on MIUI. Something is wrong on either Google or Samsung side. Probably the latter.